# Box2D kick start AndEngine?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have developed simple 2D games with AndEngine but now I want to make games using Physics Engine. I am using AndEngine as game development engine but there is no tutorials available. I am stuck in tons of information. I have read Box2d manual on their site.

If you know please share tutorials.

**Edit**

```
if you know any open source game build with AndEngine+Box2d then please share URI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box2d is just a physics engine, it does present nothing on the screen. It just makes physics simulation. How this simulation results will be represented on the screen is totally up to you: it can be a stream of positions printed on the screen, an image which position is synced with b2Body's position or anything else you like.

So you can read any Box2d tutorial you like (a lot can be found in google). I suggest you starting with box2d manual coming with box2d.

Comment: I am using andEngine and its wrapper to call native code in Java. I have already read their manual. I know about basics but most of the things like velocity, gravity, restitution are hit and trial. :-(

Comment: @Algo: Actually gravity, velocity, forces, density, joints work totally the same as the do in the real life. Restitution behaviour is well documented in the manual. You can just play with the friction.